# How much can hardware to manage for cantilever load & sheer weight on a built out faux beam that will support barn door bookcase?

Tags: beam

### Situtation & Context

Plan to hand a bookcase on a barn door in front of this opening. It will open in front of a sliding door that has a vertical blind that sits ~4.25" from drywall face.

To do this I need to sister/build out a "beam" that is 14' long from wall to wall that can support the material and the bookcase.

**questions** at end

[image: fourteen foot span]

#### Idea

1. remove drywall in front of headers (fireplace & slider)
2. reinforce/fill in the fireplace headers with more supports

[image]

1. I need 5" to create enough overhang in front of the sliding doors blind

   - I will countersink 6" Grade 5 Lag Bolts &
   - Use strap iron or twist straps to attach the layers to ceiling joists (24" on center)

     - I have 3/4" strap iron, I'm considering wrapping each of the layers if I can figure how to hold them tight to the ceiling.
   - **layer**:

     - two 2x6 kiln-dried pine + 1.75 LVL engineered beam + then a TBD veneer  (likely rough-cut 4x8x3/4 sheet of fir)
   - Additionally, instead, of lag bolts, I'll likely use full bolt & nuts w/ washers to the fireplace 2x10 header

*in the picture below none of these materials are what will be used but were scraps I had to at hand to show the layering idea... two 2x6 + 1.75 LVL + 3/4 sheet*
[image: not to scale or actual materials]

#### Questions

1. Number of lag bolts to go across the 14' expanse?

   - I figured two every two feet with ~8" between them vertically.
2. size of lag bolts?  6" grade 5, but... 1/4" or 3/8"

   - Referenced this [How much weight can lagbolts hold, or how can I support this piece of slate on a wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/74236/how-much-weight-can-lagbolts-hold-or-how-can-i-support-this-piece-of-slate-on-a) and https://askinglot.com/how-much-weight-can-a-lag-bolt-in-a-stud-hold
3. examples of how to strap a beam tight to trusses in the ceiling?

Comment: "*How much can hardware to manage for cantilever load & sheer weight on a built out faux beam that will support barn door bookcase?*"  i can  not wrap my head around that question/statement. If i understand your project correctly, you want to put a bookshelf on a barn door, all of the weight of the books will be on the barn door hardware. correct?

Comment: A) A drawing (even if a rough pencil sketch with dimensions) of what you're proposing would be very helpful. B) How much do you expect this to weigh? C) Are you 100% committed to this or are you open to options that may make your life easier?